# HoughCircles circle detection using opencv and python-

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, detection

I am trying to use OpenCV's (Hough)Circle detection to.. detect circles. I created a solid circle on a black background, tried to play with the parameters, used blur and everything, but I am just not able to make it find anything.

Any ideas, suggestions etc. would be great, thank you!

my current code is something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

"""
params = dict(dp=1,
              minDist=1,
              circles=None,
              param1=300,
              param2=290,
              minRadius=1,
              maxRadius=100)
"""

img = np.ones((200,250,3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(50, 80, 1):
    for j in range(40, 70, 1):
        img[i][j]*=200

cv2.circle(img, (120,120), 20, (100,200,80), -1)


gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 200, 300)

cv2.imshow('shjkgdh', canny)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
              param1=100,
              param2=30,
              minRadius=0,
              maxRadius=0)

print circles
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('circles', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Ok, for some reason it suddenly works with quite a few parameters. I went through everything since yesterday without anything working, but now it does. It doesn't make much sense to me, but well...

Comment: Hough circles is a little.. tricky, in practice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code is working just fine. The problem is in your `HoughCircles` threshold parameters.

Let's try to understand the parameters that you're using from [OpenCV Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles):

> param1 – First method-specific parameter. In case of CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT
>   , it is the higher threshold of the two passed to the Canny() edge
>   detector (the lower one is twice smaller).
>
> param2 – Second method-specific parameter. In case of
>   CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT , it is the accumulator threshold for the circle
>   centers at the detection stage. The smaller it is, the more false
>   circles may be detected. Circles, corresponding to the larger
>   accumulator values, will be returned first.

So, as you can see, internally the HoughCircles function calls the Canny edge detector, this means that you can use a gray image in the function, instead of their contours.

Now reduce the `param1` to 30 and `param2` to 15 and see the results in the code that follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.ones((200,250,3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(50, 80, 1):
    for j in range(40, 70, 1):
        img[i][j]*=200

cv2.circle(img, (120,120), 20, (100,200,80), -1)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
              param1=30,
              param2=15,
              minRadius=0,
              maxRadius=0)

print circles
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('circles', img)

k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: HoughCircles]

Comment: Thank you :) I displayed the canny results to get a better idea about what it HoughCircles is actually working with. The canny results always looked clean and the same tho which probably caused the biggest part of my confusion. Somehow I managed to always use parameters that didn't fit even tho I have been trying out quite a few different parameters.
Since the canny image seems to be the same with working and not working parameters, I am still not sure why some parameters work while others don't.

Comment: How is this working with maxRadius=0? Surely that would restrict any circles from appearing?

Comment: @ComputerScientist if you read the Documentation for the [HoughCircle](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles) you can see that `maxRadius` and `minRadius` default values are 0. So, you are not applying any threshold for the radius size. Hence, getting all the circles in the image.

Answer (score 12):

**If you're not getting HoughCircles to bring you pixel perfect solutions for obvious circles then you're not using it right**

Your mistake is you're trying to hand-tune your hyperparameters by yourself.  That's not going to work.  Have the computer auto-tune the parameters for you:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import signal

from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import copy

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
orig_image = np.copy(image)
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

circles = None

minimum_circle_size = 100      #this is the range of possible circle in pixels you want to find
maximum_circle_size = 150     #maximum possible circle size you're willing to find in pixels

guess_dp = 1.0

number_of_circles_expected = 1          #we expect to find just one circle
breakout = False

max_guess_accumulator_array_threshold = 100     #minimum of 1, no maximum, (max 300?) the quantity of votes 
                                                #needed to qualify for a circle to be found.
circleLog = []

guess_accumulator_array_threshold = max_guess_accumulator_array_threshold

while guess_accumulator_array_threshold > 1 and breakout == False:
    #start out with smallest resolution possible, to find the most precise circle, then creep bigger if none found
    guess_dp = 1.0
    print("resetting guess_dp:" + str(guess_dp))
    while guess_dp < 9 and breakout == False:
        guess_radius = maximum_circle_size
        print("setting guess_radius: " + str(guess_radius))
        print(circles is None)
        while True:

            #HoughCircles algorithm isn't strong enough to stand on its own if you don't
            #know EXACTLY what radius the circle in the image is, (accurate to within 3 pixels) 
            #If you don't know radius, you need lots of guess and check and lots of post-processing 
            #verification.  Luckily HoughCircles is pretty quick so we can brute force.

            print("guessing radius: " + str(guess_radius) + 
                    " and dp: " + str(guess_dp) + " vote threshold: " + 
                    str(guess_accumulator_array_threshold))

            circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, 
                cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
                dp=guess_dp,               #resolution of accumulator array.
                minDist=100,                #number of pixels center of circles should be from each other, hardcode
                param1=50,
                param2=guess_accumulator_array_threshold,
                minRadius=(guess_radius-3),    #HoughCircles will look for circles at minimum this size
                maxRadius=(guess_radius+3)     #HoughCircles will look for circles at maximum this size
                )

            if circles is not None:
                if len(circles[0]) == number_of_circles_expected:
                    print("len of circles: " + str(len(circles)))
                    circleLog.append(copy.copy(circles))
                    print("k1")
                break
                circles = None
            guess_radius -= 5 
            if guess_radius < 40:
                break;

        guess_dp += 1.5

    guess_accumulator_array_threshold -= 2

#Return the circleLog with the highest accumulator threshold

# ensure at least some circles were found
for cir in circleLog:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    output = np.copy(orig_image)

    if (len(cir) > 1):
        print("FAIL before")
        exit()

    print(cir[0, :])

    cir = np.round(cir[0, :]).astype("int")

    for (x, y, r) in cir:
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([orig_image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**The above code converts this:**
[image: Original]

**To this:**

[image: HoughCircles]

For more information about what this is doing, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46500223/445131

Comment: Cool code, that works reasonably well! Just some comments. It seems that minimum_circle_size is not being used at all. I would change "if guess_radius < 40" to if guess_radius < minimum_circle_size". Also "cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT" is now "cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT"

Comment: That code was written in a hurry so there are bugs.  The code was a brownian-motion attempt to "figure out which radius of circle is the one I want" since houghcircles returns many.  And so knowing the exact radius of the circle you want, houghcircles produces a perfect result.  The problem with the internal voting system of Houghcircles is it finds invalid circles in the imperfections in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a GUI for this algorithm that you can change parameters on time to see how it works. Here you can see it from Github:

Github link: https://github.com/pwwiur/hough-counter

### Installation:

Clone it to your directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/pwwiur/hough-counter.git
```

Install requirements:

```
pip install numpy opencv-python matplotlib pillow
```

Run:

```
python main.py
```

### Demo

[image]