# How to get circle center coordinates using python?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, coordinates, geometry

I able to detect circle center using hough circle, but i need to find the circle "center coordinates" using x and y in python. Anyone can explain it with the code? I am newbie in programming especially in python. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HoughCircles circle detection using opencv and python-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254287/houghcircles-circle-detection-using-opencv-and-python)

Comment: @Miki  i mean that i would find the x and y coordinates..
I succes to detect the circle center.. but, still cannot show up x and y in program.. thanks..

Comment: At the end of the script there is an example on how to access x (`i[0]`) and y (`i[1]`) coordinates

Comment: okay, got it.. Sorry not notice that thing at all.. Thank you @Miki